# Ford Fusion 09 starts sometimes and sometimes it won't start

Tags: ford, battery, starting, fusion

Recently my car has had trouble starting, well sometimes it turns on and sometimes it doesn't and i have to either wait a few minutes or sometimes it won't even turn on anymore. I changed the starter and even got a new battery as the problem continued. I had the vehicle checked out by a mechanic twice but it just so happened that each time it was checked the car started without a problem >.> they said that maybe the battery was starting to go bad so I got a new one. What seems to be the problem? It does make a sound like a little vacuum noise when I try to start it and the radio and lights work when its on.I even took it out for a long drive and it didn't break down or have a problem.All in all I'm looking for a solution as I want to sell this car soon and I honestly don't know what to check.

Comment: Sorry I wish Icould helpas I'm having the same problem fo past two weeks. My mechanic is pulling his hair out can't get to the bottom of the problem. He thought maybe the sensors. Timing belt, crank shaft. My car always started no problem up until 2weeks ago. Never thought much about it when it didn't start first go that morning. Went shopping a bit reluctant again. 3rd time it actually was more reluctant but it did start.Since then my mechanic had it for a week starting it no problem then not startin. Days later tried again no problem. Brings it back to me 1hr later wouldn't start. Came the n

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Update it was the starter fuse.
Basically I called my mechanic again and guess what...? The car started when he checked it >.> so he checked everything and predicted it to be a starter fuse so he swapped it out and so far no problems have occured. Hopes this helped anyone with this problem.